# Are "for...in" loops in Javascript always bad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a situation that I'm trying to make work with an `array`, but I just don't think it will. I want to have a list of objects, each with a unique ID, and I want to be able to easily reference a particular object without having to loop through the array searching for that ID.

If I use an `object` I can easily use the unique ID as the key and the object as the value. However, if I use an object instead of an array I'll have to use a `for...in` loop, and I know there are issue surrounding that if someone using my code has extended `Object.prototype`.

**So here's my question:**

Is it really that common that people extend `Object.prototype` that I should be weary of using it? Are there other reasons why I wouldn't want to use a `for...in` loop?

On the other hand, is the performance hit of looping through an array looking for a unique ID so minimal that I shouldn't worry about?

(For the record, the array will probably have fairly few elements in it, but I'll be accessing it very frequently. Also, the code I'm writing will be a jQuery plugin, so I have no control over what other bad code people are combining it with.)

**UPDATE:**

Based on advice from @nnnnnn, I set up a jsperf test and here are the results:
http://jsperf.com/accessing-object-properties-vs-iterating-over-arrays

Basically, though the object way is slightly faster, the difference is negligible. Still, using `for...in` with `hasOwnProperty` seems cleaner.

Comment: No. They are only generally "bad" when one uses the construct over an *array*, with the expectation of a for-each that is in other languages. (The answers cover the rest.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So here's my question:
>
> Is it really that common that people extend Object.prototype that I should be weary of using it? Are there other reasons why I wouldn't want to use a for...in loop?

No it's not common, but it does happen. You should use a for..in loop anyway, but with [`.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) as shown in the other answers.

I can't think of any reasons to *not* use a for..in (on an object; obviously you don't use it on an array).

> On the other hand, is the performance hit of looping through an array looking for a unique ID so minimal that I shouldn't worry about?

Well you mentioned that your array won't have many elements, but still I think that even if it performed well it would needlessly complicate your code given that you don't have to do it at all for objects. On the other hand using `.hasOwnProperty()` is a minor complication that effectively becomes part of the syntax of each for..in.

You can setup a test of the performance here: http://jsperf.com/

Answer (score 5):

Even if someone does extend the prototype, you can use [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) property to exclude these members. [This is exactly what Sugar.js recommends](http://sugarjs.com/native):

```js
var s = 'cat', key;
for(key in s) {
  if(s.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key);
  }
}
```

Now according to Sugar, `for..in` is the accepted loop for object literals, but you can also use an iterator like `$.each` for jQuery or `_.each` for Underscore.js.

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` only works on objects that inherit from `Object`. I know I could do this, but I was really hoping to find a solution that didn't involve creating a new "class". I was also hoping for an answer to my question about iterating over arrays vs objects from a performance perspective.

Comment: @Philip Walton - Wait, what? You have objects that don't inherit from `Object`? Why do you think you need to create a new "class" to use `.hasOwnProperty()`?

Comment: @nnnnnn Doh! Thanks for pointing that out. I was (mistakenly) under the impression that `hasOwnProperty` didn't work on object literals, rather only on other objects that inherit from the root `Objecet` class.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method in a `for..in` loop in order to distinguish stuff farther up the prototype chain from stuff assigned to your object.

Or you could keep your own list of "keys" assigned to a given object.